# How to solve one-sided and two-sided Chebyshev's inequality?

Tags: probability, inequality

I am stuck with this task. Can somebody help me to explain how to solve the problem with Chebyshev's inequality?

> The man earns Xn bitcoins on day n, where
>    Xn are independent and identically distributed random variable with
>    mean 6 and Var = 9. Use one-sided and two-sided Chebyshev's inequality
>    to solve estimate the probability that the total amount the man earns
>    in 100 days is less than 510

Comment: One may downvote you because of clarity (visual there) . You shall precise for people who don't clearly see what your talking about.

Comment: Do you know what Chebyshev's inequality is?

Comment: @Pagode what exactly is unclear here?

Comment: As @TonyHellmuth says , and try to advise you (I don't have particular problem with your post but I see downvote so I want you to know maybe why : I guess) . Precise which Tchebycheff inequality you use with a Latex presentation if possible (I know maybe you need more time and are urged )

Comment: It's not that something is unclear. It's that you really need to show some sort of working out, example, or just explain what concept you don't understand. :) Otherwise answers will be too specific or too broad.

Answer (score 0):

One sided Chebychev's inequality:

$$P(X\le \mu - a) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + a^2}\tag1$$

$$P(X\ge \mu + a) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + a^2}\tag2$$

$E(X_i) = 6,E (X) = E(100 X) =100E(X_i) = 600$

$Var (X_i) = 9,   Var(X) = Var(nX_i) = nVar(X_i) = 900$

Using (1) $$P(X<510) =  P(X\le 600 - 90) \le \frac{900}{900 + 8100} = \frac{1}{10}$$

Using (2)$$P(X>690) =  P(X\le 600 + 90) \le \frac{900}{900 + 8100} = \frac{1}{10}$$

Two Sided Chebychev's inequality, you get a relaxed bound

$$P(|X-\mu| > t) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{t^2}\tag3$$

Using (3) $$P(|X-600| > 90)  =P(X-600>90) + P(X-600<-90) = P(X>690) + P(X<510) \le \frac{900}{8100} = \frac{1}{9}$$

$$P(X>690) + P(X<510) \le \frac{1}{9}$$

$$P(X<510) \le \frac{1}{9}$$